# how to use pseudo-field in facet

Tags: solr, solr6

I generated a pseudo-field by function query like `"fl=new_field:sum(a,b)","a,b"` are defined numeric fields in manage-schema. I want to know how I can make the pseudo-field or the function expression can be used by facet? I want to use it for bucketing.

Comment: I don't think you can use a pseudo field through the name, but you can use the `sum` function directly in your facet definition as long as you use the JSON Facet API: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Faceted+Search - does that work for you?

Comment: Thanks  MatsLindh,I know JSON Facet API enable to to compile statistics by "sum,max.."functions,but I want to use the functions like term fields rather than statistics.